# Configure second SQL Server Alias for named instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my devopment environment (Win 2008 server) are running two sql server 2008 instances (default and named instance).

Already one Sql alias is configured and pointing to the default instance. I want a second alias pointing to the named instance but have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand SQL Server Native Client Configuration, right-click Aliases, and then click New Alias.

In the Alias Name box, type the name of the alias. Client applications use this name when they connect.

In the Server box, type the name or IP address of a server. **For a named instance append the instance name.**

In the Protocol box, select the protocol used for this alias. Selecting a protocol, changes the title of the optional properties box to Port No, Pipe Name, or Connection String.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445.aspx